# How to properly deserialize Jackson (JSON) together with Hibernate

Tags: java, angularjs, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

We have been having some issues with getting Jackson and Hibernate to integrate with each other. When decoupling objects from Hibernates Proxy-magic, suddenly Hibernate starts to do INSERTS when we want to UPDATE objects, probably since the object deserialized using Jackson is detached for Hibernate. We have solved it temporarily by defining our own builders

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = PlanBuilder.class)
public class Plan {
    ...
```

Using this pattern we can control when we need to fetch objects from the database and merge with the updated Json data (if we are doing an UPDATE for instance). We can also handle null values, @JsonIgnore attributes etc.

We did this since if we use @JsonIgnore on some attribute Hibernate thinks that the object that is being deserialized and updated doesnt have any relations and simply removes them from the database which is not something we want, we solve it by syncing this in the builders.

However, this does not feel like a robust or flexible solution. Have anyone else encountered this problem and how did you solve it?

Best Regards! / D

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate would only start performing `INSERT`'s if the object that you are trying to update doesn't have its ID field set. So if Jackson is failing to deserialize the ID correctly, then Hibernate would insert the object because it doesn't know that it exists.

In my current project, if I need an instance of a particular object that I have an ID for, I make an REST call (say to /user/) passing in the User's ID that I have on the front end. My controller picks this call up, calls the UserService which is where my Hibernate Session is created (method annotated `@Transactional`) which then calls my UserDAO which performs the actual `SELECT`. The User object gets passed back from the DAO to the Service layer to the Controller, and because I have my controller annotated with `@ResponseBody` it is automatically serialized into JSON by Jackson.

If I want to pass an object in to be created/updated, I pass it in using a RESTful POST or PUT. The object is serialized by the front-end into JSON and passed in the request body. My controller has a parameter annotated with `@RequestBody` which gets Jackson to deserialise it when its received. I then call my Service layer and the pattern follows like my example above.

The advantage of this is that Jackson and Hibernate never have to know that the other exists. Jackson simply turns your JSON into an object which gets managed by Hibernate.

Comment: Im sorry. I meant with other issues as well. For instance if an object has a relationship: ManyToMany for instance, and we also have @JsonIgnore on that relationship, Hibernate figures when we want to update an object that "this object doesnt have any objects as relatives and will remove that coupling. We solve it by syncing with the database in the builders if the json-object doesnt contain this JsonIgnored attribute.